# Insert into historical table ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord, historical-db

I have some table `events` that is populated by users. My users can edit data in this table, but when this is done I'm required to populate **another database** with an `event_historics` table.

I tried to

```
 @event = Event.find(id_event)
 EventHistoric.create @event.map(&:serializable_hash)
```

But i get an `undefined method map for` error.

Using the object directly in the `create` function gives an `undefined method stringify_keys for` error.

Is there an easy workaround for this?

Comment: `map` is a function used in array not any instance but you are using it in an instance `@event.map` and instance is `@event`

Comment: you can use EventHistoric.create(@event.attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for here is:

```
EventHistoric.create @event.attributes
```